# How to write this JavaScript function properly?

Tags: javascript

Currently learning web development, after completing HTML/CSS I'm now in JavaScript fundamentals (boy is it way tougher than the first two!), and in this practice project I'm looking to grab the absolute values of userGuess - secretActualNumber and computerGuess - secretActualNumber, and then compare them to see which one is closer to the secret number. So far I've tried this.

```
const compareGuesses = (userGuess , computerGuess, secretActualNumber) => {

    Math.abs(userGuess-secretActualNumber);

    Math.abs(computerGuess-secretActualNumber);

}
```

In order to compare both of those, I was thinking I need to implement the "difference" function of JS. But I've been struggling to make use that, to compare these two items, and to then result in a true/false. (true being if the user is closer, and false if the computer is closer).

Let me know what you think!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Save results to variables and then compare them:

```
const compareGuesses = (userGuess, computerGuess, secretActualNumber) => {

    var userDiff = Math.abs(userGuess-secretActualNumber);

    var computerDiff = Math.abs(computerGuess-secretActualNumber);

    return userDiff <= computerDiff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return true only if the user is closer.

```js
const compareGuesses = (userGuess , computerGuess, secretActualNumber) =>
  Math.abs(userGuess-secretActualNumber) < Math.abs(computerGuess-secretActualNumber);
```

You'll want to use `<=` instead of `<` if you want it to return true when equal.

```js
const compareGuesses = (userGuess , computerGuess, secretActualNumber) =>
  Math.abs(userGuess-secretActualNumber) <= Math.abs(computerGuess-secretActualNumber);
```

Comment: Hi there. If they are equal, I'd like the user to return true! 

What else would need to be adjusted to account for that?

Comment: `Math.abs(userGuess-secretActualNumber) < Math.abs(computerGuess-secretActualNumber)` to Math.abs(userGuess-secretActualNumber) `<=` Math.abs(computerGuess-secretActualNumber)